# How to get console width without using ncurses?

Tags: cross-platform, console-application, ncurses, fcntl

What I need is only the console width, so it is better to not depend on another library that provides many other functions. In addition, the user of my library probably don't have `ncurses` dev headers installed; so if I remove the dependency on `ncurses`, there will be less claims from my user.

I have downloaded ncurses source code and had a brief look at it, but failed to grasp the key code for collecting the console width. I know `fcntl()` can do it, but Windows probably don't have it. Could anybody tell me how to get the width in a cross-platform way?

Answer (score 0):

You find it in the COLUMNS environment variable.